# Бесконечная карусель блоков

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть 4 блока:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" >
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    This is some text within a card body.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Как средствами JS или CSS сделать так, что бы эти 4 блока прокручивались горизонтально автоматически после загрузки страницы в бесконечном цикле? Например как здесь [Тинькофф](https://www.tinkoff.ru/invest/)

Comment: @Sevastopol' наверно это просто современно использовать plugin - и меньше веса и кода в html

Comment: @Sevastopol' ну смотри - это троякий подход - мы освобождаем js то  есть не пишем его вообще но зато html и css разрастается до небес в размерах - вместо этого и применяют всякие хаки в виде плагинов ...что бы это автоматизировать как то

Comment: @Sevastopol' и последнее скажу что не бывает современных сайтов на css - большенство фишек делается имено на css но это в купе с javascript - что бы это проверить возьми пару коммерческих заказов - или поработай на студию - где будут реальные заказчики или хозяин студии - где будут требования - вот там ты узнаешь что такое вёрстка в современном стиле ...или другими словами узнаешь за что платят деньги

Comment: @Sevastopol' конечно килограммы css но они сгенерированы а не написаны руками

Comment: @Sevastopol' за то там дубликат блока что уже не айс

Comment: @Sevastopol' ну вот видишь уже продублировал - а это должен делать js - на ЯП мы просто вызовем функцию и все слайды сами подстроятся

Comment: @Sevastopol' в твоём примере блок продублирован ..в коммерческой вёрстке это не канает

Comment: @Sevastopol' чем коммерческая отличается от `как я хочу` ? Хотя бы тем что есть требование - красиво - современно - эстетично - за бабки

Comment: @Sevastopol' ладно я скажу так - у меня была своя студия - и у меня были реальные заказчики - и 90% заказчиков говорили одно и тоже - валидно красиво и рабочим не одно и тоже что и современно - не зря же vue react появились - это же самое можно и на обычном js сделать - верно ? но почему то применяют vue react а специальность html css верстка протухла и осталась далеко в 2000 году

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй Slick.js, там всё просто 
[Оффициальный сайт](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/),
 [Документация](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick)

Можно настроить слайдер для этого. Включить `autoplay` и поставить `autoplaySpeed` на 0. А чтобы оно не останавливалось убедится что `easing` `cssEase` стоят на `linear`

```
$('.autoplay').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  speed: 2000
  easing: 'linear',
  cssEase: 'linear',

  //Убрать возможность ручного скролла
  arrows: false,
  swipe: false,
  draggable: false
});
```

Как то так

[Тоже самое в CodePen](https://codepen.io/DarkRou/pen/bGVrwpM)